# say command says wrong text (for some voices)

Tags: terminal, text-to-speech

I'm running 10.8.5 and installed some of the newer text-to-speech voices, including "Samantha" (aka Siri), "Tom", and "Jill". They work fine, except for the word "seq":

```
say -v Jill seq
```

produces the spoken words: "the following".

```
say -v Samantha "consider seq question"
```

produces the spoken words: "consider the following question".

I tried the above test on each of the voices I have installed, and only "Samantha", "Tom", and "Jill" exhibit this behavior.

I haven't found any other words that produce wrong output, but there may be more.

Comment: I can't find Jill on 10.9.3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These voices come from Nuance. If you try their [Vocalizer Demo](http://enterprisecontent.nuance.com/vocalizer5-network-demo/index.html?utm_source=ZoomNews%20from%20Ai%20Squared&) you can hear that "seq" is replaced by "the following" there as well.

This appears to be similar to Nuance's recognition of "[homographic abbreviations](https://downloads.avaya.com/elmodocs2/ir/r1_3/IR_R13_Doc_CD/CD/html/externaldocs/Vocalizer_30_Developers_Guide.pdf)", where Nuance will attempt to convert an abbreviation into the full word.

I have noticed that there are other words that are interpreted

- `e.g.` "for example"
- `sat.` "Saturday"
- `mar.` "March"

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, what’s spoken is not what you expected to be spoken. I’m not sure I would call it “wrong”, though. “seq” is a fairly obscure dictionary entry in the first place, and “the following” is one possible expansion of this abbreviation (although I think “and the following” would be better), e.g. in literature references:

Knuth, Art of Computer Programming Vol 1, pp 329 seq.