# Speak screen saying "one dollar?"

Tags: ios, accessibility, text-to-speech

Every few sentences, the phone speaks a phrase that sounds like "one dollar." It's not in the text of the screen. Anyone know what this is?

This also happens on the Uber driver app when it’s speaking instructions. It’s the weirdest thing. It happens on multiple web sites (not just Uber.com), though not all.

I was thinking maybe it has something to do with HTML tags ???

I also found this question:  [say command says wrong text (for some voices)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130961/say-command-says-wrong-text-for-some-voices?rq=1)
and am not sure if it's related. I don't have special voices installed on my phone. I'm just using the female voice.

> **Listen here:**
>
> https://soundcloud.com/user-339437908/one-dollar#t=0:04
>
> Recorded from https://www.uber.com/a/drive-pp/?exp=nyc
>
> Note that the phrase "one dollar" is spoken quite a few times throughout the recording and those words do not appear anywhere in the
> text.

**Or**

> **Test it out yourself:**
>
> Go to Settings>General>Accessibility>Speech and enable "Speak Screen".
> Then try it here: https://www.uber.com/a/drive-pp/?exp=nyc

---

** **Edit:** **

I was digging around and I noticed I was using the "female voice" setting under Siri, but the Accessibility settings have options for multiple voices. Using some of the other voices, the extra words were not spoken, making this question very much related to the linked question. However, the linked question refers to a specific word being spoken as a different word. I am concerned with why this extra phrase is being inserted into the text. The bounty remains and I hope someone can answer. And until then I'll be using the Australian voices because they don't exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Do you happen to have a recording of it that you can share?

Comment: @Glorfindel I can make one. How do I share it?

Comment: Some sites on the Stack Exchange network have a semi-built-in option for this: https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/a/176/17390. So uploading to SoundCloud and posting the link here is the best option.

Comment: @Glorfindel thx, I will try later on today

Comment: Adding an URL to a page showing this behavior would also be helpful

Comment: @patrix Yes, added

Comment: This is "Skip to $1..."  and $1 is a [formal parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Parameters_and_arguments).

Comment: @klanomath Interesting. What does it mean and why is it adding it to the spoken words?

Comment: @Shades It's probably in the PHP code and works as a placeholder: [What do $1 and $2 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754611/what-do-1-and-2-mean). I don't have access to the US-site right now - I'm always redirected to the German site - and can't really prove it. I will use a US-VPN access later today and check this.

Comment: This also happens in [Carrot Weather](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/carrot-weather-talking-forecast-robot/id961390574?mt=8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resolved

This was a **bug** in **iOS 11 beta** 3 (and possibly 1 and 2). It was [reported](https://community.infinite-flight.com/t/hearing-runway-one-dollar-land-on-ios-11-beta/130090) as happening in other apps on phones running the beta.

[This post](http://www.openradar.me/33339345) reports it as a bug with [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesisvoice).

**As of beta 4, this seems to have been corrected**. If you are still experiencing this issue, upgrade to latest beta.

Answer (score 7):

I can't really get the code of the web page/app, but checking older/similar JavaScript/PHP code of uber.com it seems to be a hick-up of the Text-to-Speech framework which probably stumbles over a snippet similar to `..."common.step-to-main-content":"Skip to $1"...` with $1 being a positional or a formal parameter with the "value": *main_content* or *main content*.

The above code (without $1 but with *main content*) can be found in [uber.com/drive/new-york/ (Google Cache)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:It8a79_lEpoJ:https://www.uber.com/drive/new-york/&num=1&hl=de&gl=de&strip=0&vwsrc=1).

---

I'm no coder so I might use the wrong terms...

Comment: I’m pretty sure the word “skip” is part of the menu. If you listen to the entire recording, the phrase “one dollar” is spoken multiple times without the word “skip.” I like the line of thinking here though

Comment: @Shades All the text spoken *near* $1 in your soundcloud example can be found in the Google Cache link. The other occurrences of $1 are probably related to a/the user name. Checking the surrounding code it isn't as obvious though. I may be wrong the value of $1 in my answer though...

Comment: Yes, it does in fact look like there are parameters embedded into the HTML as was my original thinking. There is ${parameter} all over the place.